# loading modules from cron job

Tags: cron

I've got a cronjob that executed a shell script
Inside my shell script i do a 
module load tww/perl

but it gives me

```
module: command not found
```

what can i do? I have at least 10 modules I need to load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems likely your script depends on an environment setting, such as the initial path to your modules, that cron doesn't know about. By default the cron environment is quite austere, or so it is on *nix systems I use.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I'm late but replacing

```
#!/bin/bash
```

by

```
#!/bin/bash -l
```

works for me.